# How to save the data from data-view in R (when the workspace is reset)

Tags: r, view, save, viewpanel

I was using RStudio to geocode locations overnight. Our IT reset my system without permission. Now all the workspace is gone. Fortunately, the data view pane is open and I can see my data but I cannot save it. Is there a way to save it? or copy-paste it?

simply can I save from data that I got from:

```
View(mydata)
```

I tried copy-pasting it to excel but that only pastes a few hundreds although I select and copy all 6000 data points.

thank you

Comment: If you can do `View(mydata)`, you should be able to use `saveRDS` on `mydata` too

Comment: Hi I cannot do View(mydata). I am just able to see the results of view(mydata) before system resets. it is an odd case. there is no mydata at all! I need a view a way to some how copy. I even tried to print but RStuido crashes every time I try print.